# Dagger Dependency Injection in main function

Tags: kotlin, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am calling a function in a class S3FileOperationsAdapter from the main function in my kotlin code. I am injecting the class S3FileOperationsAdapter in the main function file. So it looks like

```
class Runner {
    @set:Inject
    lateinit var s3FileOperationsAdapter: S3FileOperationsAdapter

    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
       s3FileOperationsAdapter.readFunction()
    }
}
```

Now the issue is:

- When I try to run the above code, I get the error `Error: Main method is not static in class com.amazon.bram.sim.BatchJobRunner, please define the main method as:`. This is understandable.

And we can only make a static function within an object in kotlin. So upon doing that, I cannot Inject the dependency, because `Dagger does not support injection into Kotlin objects`. So it feels like a deadlock.

My question is, I want to inject the dependency in this file anyhow so that I can call the respective function. And I am calling this function from the "fun main()" in kotlin. How can I achieve this? Has anyone ever faced this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to inject anything in Dagger, you must first create an instance of your component.  Since no code at all will run before `fun main()`, this needs to be done during `main` itself (or in a field initializer).

After creating an instance of the component, you can ask it for an instance of `S3FileOperationsAdapter` directly.

```kotlin
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    // Create the component.
    val component = DaggerMyComponent.create()
    // or use the Component.Builder or Component.Factory you defined for MyComponent.

    // Get an object from the component.
    // This method should be defined in your component interface.
    val adapter = component.s3FileOperationsAdapter()

    // Use the object.
    adapter.readFunction()
}
```

If your actual code is more complicated, with multiple injected objects and a longer `main()` function, this may be a bit unwieldy.  In that case, you can extract your current `main()` into its own class and let Dagger provide that class in `main()`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Yes, in my case I had to create a Module, insert that in the component and generate the component (build project) and used the daggerComponent to inject the dependency and call other functions from the injected clases.